# How can I mount my home directory after installation

Tags: partitioning, root, home-directory

I have installed ubuntu a few months back and I had divided by drive into two partitions, an EFI partition, and a root partition but now I want a separate partition for my home directory but don't want to reinstall the whole system for that, is there any way to do this without losing any files.

And if possible can you give some recommendations on where it should be mounted as I have a 128 GB SSD where my current ubuntu is and a 1TB HDD in which I have around 300-400 GB free, so should I mount the home in the HDD while the root and EFI being in the SSD?

Comment: Boot a *live* system (so no partitions are *in-use*), create your /home, then you can copy your files to the newly created partition. Edit your *file system table* (/etc/fstab) so the new partition is mounted as /home, then boot normally & test.  If all goes well, you can return to *live* session and re-claim the space in your current /home/$USER/ (which will be shadowed by the new mount, so you won't see it during operation wasting disk space.. but doing it later like this means it can be recovered if something when wrong)..  This is what I'd do, but you should always backup.

Comment: I would not do that. There is a simpler method: put the user directories on your 2nd disc and tell the system to look there for it (see `.config/users-dirs.dir`  on how to do that). Your boot might be negatively affected by putting /home on another partition. Far less hassle to do it this way.